# controlling 2 sensor and 3 pump using millis

Tags: arduino-mega, relay, millis

i make a 3 pump for output and im using millis for it, i want to stop if rach the intervalm now in my code its still looping not realy stop for it thx

```
int pump1 = 5;//pin D5
int pump2 = 6;//pin D6
int pump3 = 7;//pin D7
float pompa1;
float pompa2;
float pompa3;
unsigned long prev_pump1    = 0;
unsigned long prev_pump2    = 0;
unsigned long prev_pump3    = 0;
unsigned long initiate_start = 0;
int pump_state1 = false;
int pump_state2 = false;
int pump_state3 = false;
```

and after this this is my loop program

```
  //-----------PUMP ALGORITHM--------------------
  long int pompa01 = pompa1*1000;//interval pump1
  long int pompa02 = pompa2*1000;//interval pump2
  long int pompa03 = pompa3*1000;//interval pump2

  unsigned long initiate_start = millis();

  //pompa1
  if(intiate_start-prev_pump1 > pompa01)
  {
    pump_state1 = !pump_state1;
    
    if(pump_state1)
    {
      digitalWrite(pump1, HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(pump1, LOW);
    }
    prev_pump1 = initiate_start;
  }
  
    //pompa2
  if(intiate_start-prev_pump2 > pompa02)
  {
    pump_state2 = !pump_state2;
    
    if(pump_state2)
    {
      digitalWrite(pump2, HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(pump2, LOW);
    }
    prev_pump2 = initiate_start;
  }

    //pompa3
  if(intiate_start-prev_pump3 > pompa03)
  {
    pump_state3 = !pump_state3;
    
    if(pump_state3)
    {
      digitalWrite(pump3, HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(pump3, LOW);
    }
    prev_pump3 = initiate_start;
  }
```

Comment: Please, copy-edit your question: make complete sentences, and pay attention to grammar and punctuation. As it stands, it is really hard to decipher.

Comment: Side note: The variable names `initiate_start` and `intiate_start` are too similar, which makes the code confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is meant as a complement to Michel Keijzers' answer. I fully agree
with his assessment: code duplication is something to be avoided, as it
greatly hurts maintainability. And I sympathise with him feeling the
urge to implement this as a proper class. ;-)

I would argue, however, that between the simplistic version of the OP's
code, and the fully object-oriented one of that answer, there is an
intermediate step that is worth targeting as the next thing to learn. I
mean: arrays and loops.

Many cases of code duplication follow a pattern roughly like this:

```cpp
// At the top of the sketch:
some_type data0 = some_value;
some_type data1 = some_other_value;
// etc.

// Within a function:
do_lots_of_stuff(data0);
do_lots_of_stuff(data1);
// etc.
```

where `do_lots_of_stuff()` may be a lot of code, rather than a single
function call (and it would indeed not be that bad if it was just a
function call).

The simple solution to this kind of code duplication is to put the
variables in an array, and process them by looping through the array:

```cpp
// At the top of the sketch:
const int data_count = ...;
some_type[data_count] = {some_value, some_other_value, ...};

// Within a function:
for (int i = 0; i < data_count; i++)
    do_lots_of_stuff(data[i]);
```

Here is my attempt at applying this technique to the OP's code. Note
that, since there are multiple variables for each pump, we need multiple
arrays:

```cpp
const int pump_count = 3;
const uint8_t pump_pins[pump_count] = {5, 6, 7};
const uint32_t pump_half_periods[pump_count] = {1000, 2500, 3200};

uint8_t pump_states[pump_count];  // LOW or HIGH
uint32_t pump_last_actuations[pump_count];  // time in ms

void setup() {
    for (int i = 0; i < pump_count; i++) {
        pinMode(pump_pins[i], OUTPUT);
    }
}

void loop() {
    unsigned long now = millis();
    for (int i = 0; i < pump_count; i++) {
        if (now - pump_last_actuations[i] >= pump_half_periods[i]) {
            pump_states[i] = (pump_states[i] == HIGH) ? LOW : HIGH;
            digitalWrite(pump_pins[i], pump_states[i]);
            pump_last_actuations[i] = now;
        }
    }
}
```

This removes all the duplication, and should be easier to maintain and
debug.

Once one is comfortable with this concept, I would argue the next step
in terms of building abstractions would be to bundle together all the
data relative to one pump into a `struct`. Then we would have a single
array (the elements of which are structs) instead of a collection of
arrays:

```cpp
// Data structure describing a pump.
struct Pump {
    const uint8_t pin;
    const uint32_t half_period;  // half period in ms
    uint8_t state;               // LOW or HIGH
    uint32_t last_actuation;     // time in ms
};

const int pump_count = 3;

Pump pumps[pump_count] = {
// pin, half-T, state, last_actuation
    {5, 1000, LOW, 0},
    {6, 2500, LOW, 0},
    {7, 3200, LOW, 0}
};
```

The body of `setup()` and `loop()` would be very similar to the previous
version, but with `pump_pins[i]` replaced by `pumps[i].pin` and so on.

The third step in the abstraction ladder would be to embed the code that
handles the data structure with the data itself in a `class`, as shown
in Michel Keijzers' answer. With the proper methods defined, the main
sketch could be reduced to something like this:

```cpp
#include "Pump.h"

Pump pumps[] = {
    Pump(5, 1000),
    Pump(6, 2500),
    Pump(7, 3200)
};

void setup() {
    for (Pump &pump : pumps)
        pump.begin();
}

void loop() {
    for (Pump &pump : pumps)
        pump.process();
}
```

I tried all these methods, and it turns out the first one (with a
collection of arrays) is the one that uses the least lines of code, and
the last one (with a class) uses the most. One could wonder then why use
more advanced abstractions, if they increase the amount of code one has
to type. The reason is, these abstractions become useful when the
program grows in complexity. On can put together all the code that deals
with the pumps in one place (maybe in a separate file), all the code
that deals with sensors in another place... and the main sketch that
puts all the pieces together remains simple.

Comment: what is a "half period in ms" ? is it a state time or what

Comment: @daffafaiz: The “period” is the time it takes the signal to repeat itself. The “half period” is half the period. “ms” is the symbol for “milliseconds”, a unit of time.

Comment: thx for that sir

Comment: and sir how if i erase the `const` it is able to edit isnt ?

Comment: @daffafaiz: Excuse me? Can you make a full sentence?

Comment: is the `const` in front of the `uint32_t` it's for fix data cant change anymore ?

Comment: @daffafaiz: Yes, it means we are not going to change that value. If your plan is to change it, then remove the `const` qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is not an answer (my previous version of the answer contained a problem, thanks Edgar Bonet for notifying and a fix for the remainder of the answer). However, I don't want to remove this answer as it may help in removing a lot of duplication. I took the liberty to convert it into a class.

It compiles, but I can't check the functionality but hopefully it helps you to continue. If there are problems, use write commands to send text to the serial to check the times and state.

Sketch:

```
#include  "Pump.h"

const int NR_OF_PUMPS = 3;

Pump pumps[NR_OF_PUMPS] = 
{
  Pump(5, 1.0),
  Pump(6, 2.5),
  Pump(7, 3.2) 
};

void setup() 
{
}

void loop() 
{
  process();
}

void process()
{
  for (int pumpIndex = 0; pumpIndex < NR_OF_PUMPS; pumpIndex++)
  {
    pumps[pumpIndex].Process(millis());
  }
}
```

Pump.h:

```
class Pump
{
public:
  Pump::Pump(int pin, float interval);
  void Process(uint32_t currentTime);

private:
  int _pin;
  float _interval;
  uint32_t _prevTime;
  bool _state;
};
```

Pump.cpp:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Pump.h"

Pump::Pump(int pin, float interval)
:
  _pin(pin),
  _interval(interval * 1000.0),
  _prevTime(0),
  _state(false)
{
}
    
void Pump::Process(uint32_t currentTime)
{
  if (currentTime - _prevTime > _interval)
  {
    _state = !_state;
    digitalWrite(_pin, _state ? HIGH : LOW);
    _prevTime = currentTime;
  }
}
```

Comment: Re “_seems that the current time is always put into the `prev` variables_”: the update of the `prev` variables is within the `if` condition that controls the actuation of the pump, which is fine. BTW, you forgot to update `_prevTime` in the example you provide.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Good catch, thanks for the improvements.

Comment: The
 prev_pump3 = initiate_star make the loop forever ? Or what ?

Comment: Not that I know, however you have a problem with the typo in the intiate/initiate variable likely.

Comment: I solved the typo this however its still lopping :(

Comment: Add some print statements to see what's wrong, that's the easiest way to debug these problems

Comment: Re “`_prevTime(millis())`”: global constructors are called before the initialization of the Arduino core. I would avoid calling core functions at this time, even though `millis()` may be harmless. It is safe to initialize `_prevTime` to zero, which is the starting value of `millis()` anyway.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I thought about that indeed. I would think the start time is quickly anyway but it could matter. Initially I initialized `_prevTime` with a separate method during `setup` but that seemed a bit overdone, as this doesn't seem a time critical application anyway.

Comment: Okaaay let me add some println for this thx for helpin me